# How to set deployment order of two ears in Wildfly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, jboss, wildfly

I've some issue regarding the deployment order of two applications inside Wildfly 8.1.
The problem is that some modules of `app2.ear` depends of modules from `app1.ear`, but `app1.ear` is deployed after `app2.ear`.

I've tried to specify a dependency for app1 like this:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="app2.ear" />
    </dependencies> 
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

But no luck, `app1.ear` fails to deploy with this error:

> {"JBAS014671: Failed services" ...  Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: app2.ear:main"}}

Any idea if it is possible and how to dot it ?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Specify the dependencies in **`META-INF/jboss-all.xml`**.

So for your `app2.ear` it can look like:

```xml
<jboss xmlns="urn:jboss:1.0">
    <jboss-deployment-dependencies xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-dependencies:1.0">
        <dependency name="app1.ear" />
    </jboss-deployment-dependencies>
</jboss>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly.  I was thinking that this method was for previous Jboss versions.

Comment: For those here looking for the solution, it might be useful to know that an ear expects its reasources to be in `src/main/application` instead of `src/main/resources`! You should thus put your `jboss-all.xml` in `src/main/application`.

Comment: in hope that someone will look at this old thread. Does this jboss-all specify a necessity or a depedency ? I.e does the dependecy need to exist, or exist and be deployed ? Will the dependant wait for it to deploy first ?

Comment: If I recall it correctly, the app2 deployment will fail when the app1.ear is not already deployed.