# Deployment order of two ears in wildfly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, jboss, wildfly

I have to set deployment order for two ears in my wildfly server. 
My two ears structure is as follows :

```
 EAR1
|
|--XYZ.war
|--rule.jar
|--common.jar

 EAR2
|
|--abc.war
|--rule.jar
|--common.jar
```

So what I need is that, I need to deploy first EAR1 in server before EAR2.

I tried a lot. Used this link [How to set deployment order of two ears in Wildfly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25605968/how-to-set-deployment-order-of-two-ears-in-wildfly).. I tried creating jboss-all.xml in EAR2 as follows :

```
<jboss xmlns="urn:jboss:1.0">
    <jboss-deployment-dependencies xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-dependencies:1.0">
        <dependency name="EAR1.ear" />
    </jboss-deployment-dependencies>
</jboss>
```

But no luck.

Then I tried using http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-deploy/configuring-jboss-as-7-deployment-order. I created jboss-deployment-structure.xml. in EAR2. As follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
   <deployment>
       <dependencies>
           <module name="deployment.EAR1.ear" />
       </dependencies>
   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I am getting the exception as follows :

```
    ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "EAR2.ear")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.module.service.\"deployment.EAR2.ear.rule.jar\".main is missing [module.resolved.service.\"deployment.EAR2.ear.rule.jar\".main]",
    "jboss.module.resolve.phase.\"deployment.EAR2.ear\".main.1 is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.configurator.ear\".main]",
    "jboss.module.resolve.phase.\"deployment.EAR2.ear.abc.war\".main.2 is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.configurator.ear\".main]",
    "jboss.module.service.\"deployment.EAR2.ear.abc.war\".main is missing [module.resolved.service.\"deployment.EAR2.ear.abc.war\".main]",
    "jboss.module.resolve.phase.\"deployment.EAR2.ear.rule.jar\".main.2 is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.configurator.ear\".main]",
    "jboss.module.service.\"deployment.EAR2.ear.ConfiguratorCommon.jar\".main is missing [module.resolved.service.\"deployment.EAR2.ear.ConfiguratorCommon.jar\".main]",
    "jboss.module.resolve.phase.\"deployment.EAR2.ear.ConfiguratorCommon.jar\".main.2 is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.configurator.ear\".main]",
    "jboss.module.service.\"deployment.EAR2.ear\".main is missing [module.resolved.service.\"deployment.EAR2.ear\".main, jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.configurator.ear\".main]"
]}
15:37:51,407 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) JBAS018559: Deployed "ojdbc6.jar" (runtime-name : "ojdbc6.jar")
15:37:51,407 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) JBAS018559: Deployed "db2jcc4.jar" (runtime-name : "db2jcc4.jar")
15:37:51,407 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) JBAS018559: Deployed "EAR2.ear" (runtime-name : "EAR2.ear")
15:37:51,407 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 34) JBAS018559: Deployed "EAR1.ear" (runtime-name : "EAR1.ear")
15:37:51,412 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.module.spec.service."deployment.configurator.ear".main (missing) dependents: [service jboss.module.resolve.phase."deployment.EAR2.ear.ConfiguratorCommon.jar".main.2, service jboss.module.resolve.phase."deployment.EAR2.ear.rule.jar".main.2, service jboss.module.service."deployment.EAR2.ear".main, service jboss.module.resolve.phase."deployment.EAR2.ear".main.1, JBAS014799: ... and 2 more ] 
      service module.resolved.service."deployment.EAR2.ear".main (missing) dependents: [service jboss.module.service."deployment.EAR2.ear".main] 
      service module.resolved.service."deployment.EAR2.ear.ConfiguratorCommon.jar".main (missing) dependents: [service jboss.module.service."deployment.EAR2.ear.ConfiguratorCommon.jar".main] 
      service module.resolved.service."deployment.EAR2.ear.abc.war".main (missing) dependents: [service jboss.module.service."deployment.EAR2.ear.abc.war".main] 
      service module.resolved.service."deployment.EAR2.ear.rule.jar".main (missing) dependents: [service jboss.module.service."deployment.EAR2.ear.rule.jar".main] 

15:37:51,471 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
15:37:51,471 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
15:37:51,471 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: WildFly 8.2.0.Final "Tweek" started (with errors) in 171584ms - Started 1607 of 1795 services (12 services failed or missing dependencies, 284 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
15:37:51,682 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015974: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: ConfiguratorCommon.jar) in 14ms
15:37:51,683 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015974: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: abc.war) in 15ms
15:37:51,687 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015974: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: rule.jar) in 19ms
15:37:51,791 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment EAR2.ear (runtime-name: EAR2.ear) in 127ms
15:37:51,890 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018558: Undeployed "EAR2.ear" (runtime-name: "EAR2.ear")
15:37:51,890 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.module.service."deployment.EAR2.ear".main (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."EAR2.ear".FIRST_MODULE_USE] 
      service jboss.module.service."deployment.EAR2.ear.ConfiguratorCommon.jar".main (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."EAR2.ear"."ConfiguratorCommon.jar".FIRST_MODULE_USE] 
      service jboss.module.service."deployment.EAR2.ear.abc.war".main (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."EAR2.ear"."abc.war".FIRST_MODULE_USE] 
      service jboss.module.service."deployment.EAR2.ear.rule.jar".main (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."EAR2.ear"."rule.jar".FIRST_MODULE_USE] 
      service jboss.module.spec.service."deployment.EAR2.ear".main (missing) dependents: [service jboss.module.service."deployment.EAR2.ear".main] 
      service jboss.module.spec.service."deployment.EAR2.ear.ConfiguratorCommon.jar".main (missing) dependents: [service jboss.module.service."deployment.EAR2.ear.ConfiguratorCommon.jar".main, service jboss.module.service."deployment.EAR2.ear".main, service jboss.deployment.unit."EAR2.ear".FIRST_MODULE_USE, service jboss.module.service."deployment.EAR2.ear.abc.war".main] 
      service jboss.module.spec.service."deployment.EAR2.ear.abc.war".main (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."EAR2.ear".FIRST_MODULE_USE, service jboss.module.service."deployment.EAR2.ear.abc.war".main] 
      service jboss.module.spec.service."deployment.EAR2.ear.rule.jar".main (missing) dependents: [service jboss.module.service."deployment.EAR2.ear.ConfiguratorCommon.jar".main, service jboss.module.service."deployment.EAR2.ear.rule.jar".main, service jboss.module.service."deployment.EAR2.ear".main, service jboss.deployment.unit."EAR2.ear".FIRST_MODULE_USE, JBAS014799: ... and 2 more ]
```

Deployment is failing.
Can someone please help me out.
Please let me know if I need to add anymore documents.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1st you are using the scanner so there is no predefined order.
If you are using WildFly 10 there is the attribute "runtime-failure-causes-rollback" on the scanner that you could set to false. Thus the 1st ear will not rollback and will detect the dependency when the 2nd starts.